# jquery only allow numbers, comma's and dashes in input type

Tags: jquery, regex

I've got a `<input type="text" name="pages" placeholder="Pagina's" />`. Now i want to only allow numbers, comma's and dashes to be in the input. How do i check this with jquery?

So i only want to allow [0-9]-,

```
$("input[name=pages]").change(function (e) {
    //check if the input was other than a comma, dash or number and return false if so.
});
```

How do i do this? I thought maybe use a regex but i can't find anything with regex in jquery.

Comment: Use the standard javascript implementations of [regex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp), remember, jQuery is just a wrapper over the DOM with some useful utility functions. It doesn't replace the core language

Comment: value is a string, use javascript string methods on it. jQuery defers to native methods for strings, math, dates etc

Comment: > can't find anything with regex in jquery http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif )

Comment: Note that a keydown handler may stop the user typing the characters you don't want, but they can still paste them or drag'n'drop them. You should do the same validation on blur or change events too.

Comment: Sorry @GlenSwift dont see how your image is going to help any further... dont see any regex there??

Comment: You should capture the text on the submittal of your form and test it then.  A keydown event will not capture anything that comes via drag/drop or copy/paste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regex expression like:

> ```
> <script>
> $("input[name=pages]").keypress(function (e) {
>
>   if (/\d+|,+|[/b]+|-+/i.test(e.key) ){
>
>       console.log("character accepted: " + e.key)
>     } else {
>       console.log("illegal character detected: "+ e.key)
>       return false;
>   }
>
> });
> </script>
> ```

and do some reseach about regular expressions here: http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: they have to be able to use backspace, how can we implement that?

Comment: Sorry mate... forgot about backspace [/b]. I edited the answer. Cheers

Comment: White Cat, this code is not working in chrome or IE, and sometimes not in FF either.. What could be the problem?